# Use vector to manipulate Chars instead of lists

Tags: haskell

I have the some code that compile and works. And then some that don't.
My concern was that the first version was soooo bloated that it crashed while running on too big arguments, so I wrote a second version with performance in mind.
The second version does't even compile. Please advice.

```
import System.Environment   (getArgs)
import Data.List            (nub)
import System.Random
import Control.Applicative  ( (<$>) )
import Control.Monad        (replicateM)

randomItem :: [a] -> IO a
randomItem xs = (xs!!)  <$> randomRIO (0, length xs - 1)

genFromMask :: [String] -> IO String
genFromMask = mapM randomItem

genMeSome :: [String] -> Int -> IO [String]
genMeSome mask n = do
  glist <- replicateM (n*10) (genFromMask mask)
  return $ take n $ nub glist

writeIt ::  FilePath -> Int -> [String] -> IO ()
writeIt fi n mask = do
    glist <- genMeSome mask n
   writeFile fi $ unlines glist

maj :: String
maj = ['A'..'Z']

numa :: String
numa = ['0'..'9']


-- | Certaines regions n'utilisent aucune des plages libres
genBra :: [String]
genBra = ["VWXYZ",maj,maj," ",numa,numa,numa,numa]

genAus :: [String]
genAus = [maj,maj,maj," ",numa,numa,numa]

main :: IO ()
main = do
  args <- getArgs
  case args of
    (mo:fi:n:_) -> case mo of
      "aus" -> writeIt fi (read n) genAus
      "bra" -> writeIt fi (read n) genBra
      _     -> error "country is not supported"
    _           -> error "wrong input, format is: genLicensePlate country file number"
```

And here is the second:

```
import System.Environment   (getArgs)
import System.Random
import Crypto.Random.AESCtr (makeSystem)
import Control.Applicative  ( (<$>) )
import qualified Data.Vector  as V
import qualified Data.Text    as T
import qualified Data.Text.IO as T

nubV :: V.Vector a -> V.Vector a
nubV va
  | V.null va              = V.empty
  | V.any (== headV) tailV = nubV tailV
  | otherwise              = headV `V.cons` nubV tailV
 where
  headV = V.head va
  tailV = V.tail va

randomItem :: RandomGen g => g -> V.Vector a -> (a,g)
randomItem g xs =
  (xs V.! fst shamble, snd shamble)
 where
  shamble = randomR (0, V.length xs - 1) g

genFromMask :: RandomGen g => g -> V.Vector (V.Vector a) -> V.Vector a
genFromMask g xs =
  if V.null xs
     then V.empty
     else fst paket `V.cons` genFromMask (snd paket) (V.tail xs)
 where
  paket = randomItem g (V.head xs)

genMeSome :: RandomGen g => g -> V.Vector (V.Vector a) -> Int -> V.Vector (V.Vector a)
genMeSome g mask n =
  V.take n $ nubV $ V.replicateM (n*10) (genFromMask g mask)

writeIt :: RandomGen g => g -> FilePath -> Int -> V.Vector (V.Vector a) -> IO ()
writeIt g fi n mask =
   T.writeFile fi $ T.unlines $ T.pack $ V.toList (V.map V.toList $ genMeSome g mask n)

maj   = V.fromList ['A'..'Z']
num a = V.fromList ['0'..'9']
vspa  = V.fromList " "
vtir  = V.fromList "-"

-- | Certaines regions n'utilisent aucune des plages libres
genBra = V.fromList [static,maj,maj,vspa,numa,numa,numa,numa]
 where
  static = V.fromList "VWXYZ"

genAus = V.fromList [maj,maj,maj,vspa,numa,numa,numa]

main :: IO ()
main = do
  g    <- makeSystem
  args <- getArgs
  case args of
    (mo:fi:n:_) -> case mo of
      "aus" -> writeIt g fi (read n) genAus
      "bra" -> writeIt g fi (read n) genBra
      _     -> error "country is not supported"
    _           -> error "wrong input, format is: genLicensePlate country file number"
```

I am trying to generate fake licenses plates, to populate an anonymous database.

EDIT1:

Here are the errors:

```
genLicensePlate.hs:22:12:
    No instance for (Eq a)
      arising from a use of `=='
    In the first argument of `V.any', namely `(== headV)
    In the expression: V.any (== headV) tailV
    In a stmt of a pattern guard for
               an equation for `nubV':
      V.any (== headV) tailV

genLicensePlate.hs:48:52:
    Couldn't match expected type `Char' with actual type
    Expected type: V.Vector Char
      Actual type: V.Vector [a]
    In the first argument of `V.toList', namely
      `(V.map V.toList $ genMeSome g mask n)'
    In the second argument of `($)', namely
      `V.toList (V.map V.toList $ genMeSome g mask n)'
```

EDIT2:

So the general idea is to use a mask to generate random Strings.
Like myFunc g [['A'..'Z'],['A'..'Z']] gives AA or ZZ or BA or FG etc...
Then I use this function to make a lot of those strings based on the mask.
After that I removes duplicate and take as many as needed (since I generate 10 times the number asked even with duplicate I am OK).
Finaly I drop it on a file.

I hope it is more clear.

Kind regards,
Sar

Comment: What compile error do you get? At what line? Also - it would help to explain a little more what you are trying to do. Can you write a simpler (smaller subset) program that has the same problem? This is unlikely to get a solutionn in the current form - very messy, very localized (as in: "as it stands it looks like you're the only one who will ever have this problem" which makes it a bad SO question, typically)

Comment: If you are concerned about performance, you shouldn't use an `Ω(n²)` algorithm to remove duplicates in a set when you can do it in `O(n log n)`

Comment: I am trying to make a function that generate a String or Text from a mask any given number of time. [['0'..'9'],['0'..'9']] can give me any two digit number like "56" or "78" for example. As for the nub function, do you have any better idea. Like I said the code crashed when trying to generate lots of Strings so I need it not to crash.

Comment: @sarfraz: Yeah, use a `HashSet` instead of a list

Comment: @sarfraz: `nub . sort` is a cheap way of getting better performance, but in your case you may have to shuffle the resulting list again, in order not to get only 'lower end' results. `nub` can then even be replaced by `map head . group`

Comment: @yatima2975 `nub . sort` won't buy you much, `nub` still goes through the entire tail. `map head . group . sort` on the other hand is `O(n*log n)`.

Comment: @DanielFischer I realised that, and edited it in just seconds before your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`nubV` needs an `Eq` constraint, since it compares elements (but you really should use a `Set` or `HashSet` or so to get a better algorithm)

```
nubV :: Eq a => V.Vector a -> V.Vector a
nubV va
  | V.null va              = V.empty
  | V.any (== headV) tailV = nubV tailV
  | otherwise              = headV `V.cons` nubV tailV
 where
  headV = V.head va
  tailV = V.tail va
```

And in `writeIt`, you lack a `map`,

```
writeIt :: RandomGen g => g -> FilePath -> Int -> V.Vector (V.Vector a) -> IO ()
writeIt g fi n mask =
   T.writeFile fi $ T.unlines $ map T.pack $ V.toList (V.map V.toList $ genMeSome g mask n)
                            --  ^^^
```

since you get a list of lists of `Char` from `V.toList (V.map V.toList $ genMeSome g mask n)`.

That fixes the two reported errors.